# Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated - Request.ServerVariables

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

To avoid the error "Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated" 
I found a number of recommendations to use the following lines before looping through the Request.ServerVariables.Keys collection:

```
IEnumerator en = Request.ServerVariables.Keys.GetEnumerator();
en.MoveNext();
```

Looking at the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx), they set the Server Variables to a collection, then iterate through that collection without calling GetEnumerator or MoveNext.

Two questions:

1. Why do we need to call GetEnumerator and MoveNext?
2. Which is the better approach if using ASP.NET and C# 4.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use:

```
 string[] keys = Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys;
 foreach(string key in keys )
 {
      if(Request.ServerVariables[key] != null)
      {
           string value = Request.ServerVariables[key];
      }
 }
```

Comment: That is what causes the error mentioned on other sites such as: http://geekswithblogs.net/congsuco/archive/2006/01/26/67123.aspx

Comment: I've updated the code similar to what ivowiblo has suggested, that being to copy the array of keys to a variable and then look through the keys.  You could also use Request.ServerVariables.CopyTo to copy the key/value pairs to a different array before your loop if you wanted to preserve the values as they were when the loop started.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to create a new collection from the server variables:

```
foreach(var key in Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.ToList())
{
    var value = Request.ServerVariables[key];
    ...
}
```

ToList() extension method will create a new List with the items. If you change the ServerVariables collection you won't be changing the collection you are iterating (as it's a new one).

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Just answering your questions:
1- Those methods are for iterating the collection. Is the framework way of managing the iteration. If you can iterate, you can use foreach.
2- The best way is to use a foreach, as it's more readable than working with enumerables.

Comment: So this would avoid the error because it is a similar approach that the MSDN article took?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `"Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated."` error, when you set `EnableViewState="False"` for controls that post back data.